# Remove underline from <li> elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Yes, I tried using text-decoration: none, nut it didn't seem to do anything. Here is my css:

```
.search-result 
{
    margin-left: -50px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2f2f2f;
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none" id="myUL">
    <li class="search-result-other-pages">
        <a>
            Početna
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="search-result">
        <a href="novosti-pc.html">
            Novosti
        </a>
    </li >
    <li class="search-result">
        <a>
            Galerija
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="search-result">
        <a>
           MMA
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Never happened before. Last time it worked with text-decoration: none, but now it doesnt. If anyone knows how to fix this, please answer. Thanks!

Comment: selector li a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 4):

Links are underlined, not `LI`s.

```
.search-result a {text-decoration: none}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#myUL li a {text-decoration: none}
```